# Centroid in Babylonian Mathematics

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Are there any problems in Babylonian mathematics that deal with finding the centroid of some plane figure?

Comment: It is difficult to imagine so, because the "centroid" needs a reasonably precise definition of a geometric shape.

Comment: Perhaps what I should have said was problems in Babylonian mathematics that were precursors to finding centroids. For example, are there any problems in which an isosceles trapezoid is horizontally divided into two parts having the same area? The intersection of the horizontal line and the vertical bisector of the trapezoid would mark the centroid. Any similar problems involving triangles? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest listed identification on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) page is

> The first explicit statement of this proposition is due to Heron of
>   Alexandria (perhaps the first century CE) and occurs in his Mechanics.
>   It may be added, in passing, that the proposition did not become
>   common in the textbooks on plane geometry until the nineteenth
>   century.

A [different](http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/303-2015/Book-essentials-A4.pdf) history page says

Pappus of Alexandria (Πάππος) 290–350 the last great mathematicians of Antiquity
His work Collection (Synagoge) in 8 volumes mainly survived: it including
geometry, recreational mathematics, doubling the cube, polygons and
polyhedra. Famous for:
1) Pappus's Theorem in projective geometry,
2) Pappus Hexagon Theorem
3) Pappus chain of circles (centers are on an
ellipse)
**4) Pappus centroid (two) theorems**

My quick skim of the interwebz did not find any direct mention of Babylonian discovery of centroids.  That doesn't mean they didn't do so, just that it will be obscure.

Comment: Even Wikipedia mentions Archimedes as finding centroids of plane figures, it is done in the Method, for example. Heron's statement is likely derived from him. The idea became current after the law of the lever was formulated, which settles the simplest case, i.e. even before Archimedes, see [Renn's 
Aristotle, Archimedes, Euclid, and the Origin of Mechanics](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.580.8174&rep=rep1&type=pdf).